# Azure monitor application start /stop timings

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I have a spring boot application is deployed to Azure Kubernetes. Currently, I have enabled HeartBeatState telemetry and by having the start azure spring boot dependency, I get HTTP requests telemetry info.

I am not sending any custom telemetry to track application start or stop events. for example I am not doing anything like:

`telemetryClient.trackEvent("Start_Up", properties, null);`

`telemetryClient.trackEvent("ShutDown", properties, null);`

I have a requirement to trace when my application came up and went down. I was wondering if there is any way I can write a query in Log Analytics in Application Insight to extract this info? My pod has label which consists of the application name which perhaps I can use in the query filter but I am not sure if there is a `Kusto` query that can extract the application start and stop timings out for me.

Comment: what do you mean that "My pod has label which consists of the application name which perhaps I can use in the query filter"?

Comment: I mean I have defined some custom labels for my pods e.g. `component_name` which is application name. So was curious if that could be used to filter on specific app with table joins but unsure which table will hold this metadata info.

Comment: can you check it in the request table -> customDimensions field? and another possible way is that if k8s is connected to log analytics, please check if the start/stop event is stored there(I'm not familiar with k8s, but for a normal azure web app, the start/stop event is stored in log analytics)?